# SQL Syntax error when replacing URLs on WordPress

Tags: sql, wordpress, url, replace

I am trying to replace the live WP URLs for a local WP version using xampp

I keep getting an error when I'm submitting:

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://www.yoursitename.com', 'http://localhost') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://www.yoursitename.com', 'http://localhost');
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'http://www.yoursitename.com','http://localhost');
```

Cant work out how to fix it, when I submit query, it shows up this:

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1

Comment: use https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/ which run and replace all your URL from entire database.

Comment: yes have tried it but it doesnt seem to work

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to adjust it that way, edit the links via editing the theme function file by using:

```
update_option( 'siteurl', 'http://www.yoursitename.com' );
update_option( 'home', 'http://www.yoursitename.com' );
```

Once that has been done you can update other URL links by using a plugin named Blue Velvet.

Comment: sorry a bit new here, what do you mean editing links via the theme function? functions.php?

Comment: Thats the one yes. add the update_option code into the very first line of the file and swap the URL to your own.